# Comparing an arrayList with a Set in java

Tags: java, arraylist, set, iteration

My set looks like this,

```
final public static Set<String> env = new HashSet<String>(
           Arrays.asList("DEV", "QA", "PREPROD", "PROD"));
```

And my arrayList will be populated dynamically from DB which will have all the 4 or lesser than that (ex: DEV,QA)

How do i find the missing elements in arraylist and print those?

Comment: `Set` has a `contains` method. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 3):

Given two collections, `a` and `b`, here is a way to list the contents of `a` that are not also in `b`.

```
a.stream()
   .filter(x -> !b.contains(x))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Without streams, you could do this:

```
for (String x : a) {
   if (!b.contains(x)) {
       System.out.println(x);
   }
}
```

Comment: @BenArnao Yes, that's the problem. You posted the same thing again, adding no value to this question.

Comment: i posted it first though

Answer (score 3):

Copy the Set and remove all of the elements in the List using the [removeAll method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)). You'll be left with a Set containing the missing ones:

```
List<String> list = ...;
Set<String> set = ...;

Set<String> copy = new HashSet<>(set);
copy.removeAll(list);
System.out.println(copy);
```

Comment: Why the overhead of another Set ... there are many other solutions to this. check out @khelwood 's response.

Comment: Well that's useful if you want to do something with the missing elements right now, not so much if you want to keep them for later use. The question also suggests that there won't be that many values in the Set, so worrying about overhead sound like premature optimization to me...

Comment: @Exception_al With all the overhead of a `Stream`. And this answer is also the suggested idiom in [the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) (see section "Set Interface Bulk Operations").

Answer (score -1):

You should use an Enum that contains all possible values in code.

Then you could do :

```
Arrays.asList(YourEnum.values()).removeAll(<elements_got_from_database>));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for (String element : array)
    if (!otherarray.contains(element))
        print(element);
```